# how to activate a component each time the parameter in the route that activetes it changes

Tags: angular-routing, angular-router

I read that the router reuses a component and its template if the only thing that changes are the route parameters

Therefore, if the component that is activated executes logic in its ngOnInit () it will only be executed the first time that the route like this activates it http://../projects/12

How can you make that logic execute when switching to path http/../projects/45

In my case I have this project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/planificador?file=src/app/planificador/components/resumen/resumen.component.ts

And when I select a new project only executes ResumenComponent's ngOnInit() method the first time

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR

[StackBlitz app.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/planificador-bfsdgk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

---

### Explanations

For this situation, we could use a custom `RouteReuseStrategy`:

#### app.module.ts

```js
export class CustomRouteReuseStrategy extends BaseRouteReuseStrategy {
  shouldReuseRoute(
    future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    const determinantParam = "proyectoId";

    if (
      !curr?.routeConfig?.path.includes(determinantParam) ||
      !future?.routeConfig?.path.includes(determinantParam)
    ) {
      return super.shouldReuseRoute(future, curr);
    }

    return future.params[determinantParam] === curr.params[determinantParam];
  }
}
```

The `BaseRouteReuseStrategy` is defined [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/route_reuse_strategy.ts#L79) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/route_reuse_strategy.ts#L108-L110) is why it didn't create a new component when a new `param` is used:

```js
shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
  return future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig;
}
```

and it returns `true` because the value of `routeConfig` from both objects(`future` and `curr`) is the first item defined in the `Routes` array in **planificador.module.ts**:

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: PlanificadorAppComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: ':empleadoId/proyectos',
      component: MainContentComponent,
    },
    {
      path: ':empleadoId/proyectos/:proyectoId',
      component: MainContentComponent,
    }
  ]
},
```

As expected, Angular builds the next navigation by traversing the route configurations and by comparing that previous state. This *state* is defined as a tree, where each notes holds meaningful information. Among this information, there is the `params` object, whose keys are the params(e.g `:proyectoId`) and the values are determined by what the URL looks like.

So, what our custom strategy does it to ensure that if the navigation concerns the route who's path is `:empleadoId/proyectos/:proyectoId`, then this route(and its component) should be reused only if this condition is true:

```js
future.params[determinantParam] === curr.params[determinantParam]
```

Furthermore, if you'd like to read more about Angular Router, you could check out these articles:

- [Angular Router: Revealing some interesting facts and features](https://indepth.dev/posts/1379/angular-router-revealing-some-interesting-facts-and-features)
- [Angular Router: Getting to know UrlTree, ActivatedRouteSnapshot and ActivatedRoute](https://andreigatej.dev/blog/angular-router-urlree)
- [Demystifying angular/router: what is RouterScroller and why is it useful ?](https://indepth.dev/posts/1366/demystifying-angular-router-what-is-routerscroller-and-why-is-it-useful-2)

Comment: Thanks you very much a great solution and a better explanation